# String comparison in Java without spaces

Tags: java, regex, string, stringbuilder, string-comparison

Folks,

I am having a little doubt with String comparison (with blank spaces in between) in Java .

**UseCase :-**
Consider the following Solr query string :-

```
  String query = ".....&ansDt:[* TO *]....";
```

Valid format for ansDt are :-

1. `ansDt : [* TO *]`
2. `ansDt : [someDate TO *]`
3. `ansDt : [* TO someDate]`
4. `ansDt : [someDate TO otherDate]`

I have two doubts:-

- Now, I need a way to check the query string for only `4th ansDt` format. If other format is encountered ( in short, if any `*` pattern is encountered in `ansDt` field) , I need to throw some message on console.
- Also I need to check for 1st, 2nd and 3rd case irrespective of blank spaces between `ansDt` & `:` & `[`. i.e `ansDt: [* TO *]`, `ansDt :[* TO *]`, `ansDt : [ * TO *]` etc are all considered same

I cannot use `String.trim( )` because it will remove only the leading and ending whitespaces for a string

How do I check that with Java String comparison ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try this regex:

```
String query = ".....&ansDt:[* TO *]....";

String pattern = ".*ansDt[\\ ]*[:][\\ ]*[\\[].*[\\ ]+TO[\\ ]+.*[\\]].*"; 

boolean test = query.matches(pattern);
```

Additional info:

```
. matches any character

.* matches any amount of characters

[\ ] matches space

[\ ]+ matches one or more spaces, used between "TO"

[\ ]* matches any amount of spaces, used between ":"

[\[] and [\]] matches "[" and "]"
```

Comment: +1, but please use StackOverflow's excellent [code formatting features](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help), as I've demonstrated;  simply wrapping text in `<code>` tags doesn't work.  I also escaped the backslashes in your regex as required by Java String literals, but you don't really need to escape the space characters (`"[\\ ]*"`); `"[ ]*"` or just `" *"` will do.

Answer (score 1):

Regex is the way to go. But for a quick fix you can try

```
    String query = ".....&ansDt : [ * TO *]...."; 
    int indexOfansDt = query.indexOf("ansDt");
    int indexOfBeginBracket = query.indexOf("[",indexOfansDt);
    int indexOfEndBracket = query.indexOf("]",indexOfBeginBracket);
    String yourString = query.substring(indexOfBeginBracket, indexOfEndBracket+1);
    System.out.println(yourString);
```

Check `yourString` for `indexOf("*")`, if it is not `-1` your format is 1,2 or 3. But there are a lot of error cases, NPEs that you have to check for.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need something more complex than a simple regex.  You've written what amounts to a four line grammar.  You should take the approach that a parser generator would: tokenize it and then execute rules to see if the tokens match your grammar.

If you can stand the big hammer of a parser generator, I'd recommend ANTLR.

Comment: Like I said, it's a big hammer.  Try an ANTLR tutorial and see if you can write a grammar for your four line case.  Or just tokenize it and bang out the "if" cases.

Answer (score 0):

This should do (for strings `s1` and `s2`):

```
s1.replace(" ", "").equals(s2.replace(" "), ""))
```

Comment: How to check for case 2 ? At time of string comparison, we might not know the value of `someDate`